# How to start an LXC LXD container in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, lxd

You are probably wondering how to install lxc/lxd in ubuntu to test your new code in a container. Then how to create an image. I will show you how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Within you command line:

```
sudo snap install lxd
```

Make sure it worked:

```
lxd --version
```

View the different lxc container images ex: ubuntu:

```
lxc image list images:ubuntu
```

Create and lxc container/image:

```
lxc launch images:ubuntu/focal <your image name>
```

Access your lxc container:

```
lxc exec <your image name> -- sudo -i
```

You are all done, go crazy messing around with your ubuntu lxc container.